# MySQL Correct Usage of From_Unixtime in Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following trigger which inserts records into Table B whenever Table A is updated. This works fine however **TableA_date** is in unix time format and I want to convert it when the trigger inserts the record in Table B.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
AFTER INSERT
ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableB SET 
    TableB_id = NEW.TableA_id, 
    TableB_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(NEW.TableA_date, '%d/%m/%y %r'),
    TableB_comment = NEW.TableA_comment;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

In my results, instead of "01/01/70 03:00:05 AM" as the converted date I get "5" - I know the format string is correct as I am able to use it in a select statement. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the data type of your `TableB.TableB_date` column?

Comment: @Arkady That's a mistake. It should be `timestamp`. Internally timestamp is stored as an int, but when you set it to timestamp MySQL handles all date conversions automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working too hard. Just leave out the format string entirely. Dates are stored as dates, not a strings.

In fact, don't even use the conversion at all! Just directly assign the date column, and MySQL will do any conversion it needs.

I'm assuming that TableA_date is stored using the `timestamp` datatype, and that TableB_date is `datetime`. (Although you may want `timestamp` for that one too.)

If you are using other datatypes like int, or char, then fix it. That's not the correct way to structure a database.

---

Just to answer your actual question (instead of telling you the correct way to do it) the date format you want is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` not what you have.